# Swift 3 - Core data One-to-One relation get value

Tags: uitableview, core-data, swift3, one-to-one

I have a one-to-one relation in my core data, using UIAlertAction I am saving some data and it is successfully saved to core data with no error

Now I want to get those data and set it to a UILabel in my tableview

This is my [Core Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Le8vg.png)

Using editActionsForRowAt I am saving the values of reps and sets

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {


    let editButton = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Edit") { (rowAction, indexpath) in

        let sets = self.workout?.muscleList?[indexpath.row]



        let inputAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Sets", message: "Enter reps and sets", preferredStyle: .alert)
        inputAlert.addTextField { (textfield:UITextField) in
            textfield.placeholder = "Sets"
        }
        inputAlert.addTextField { (textfield:UITextField) in
            textfield.placeholder = "Reps"
        }

        inputAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: .default, handler: { (action:UIAlertAction) in



            let setsTextField = inputAlert.textFields?.first
            let repsTextField = inputAlert.textFields?.last

            if repsTextField?.text != "" && setsTextField?.text != "" {
                print("results: ",(setsTextField?.text)!, " sets + ", (repsTextField?.text)!," reps")


                sets?.setAndrep?.sets = setsTextField?.text
                sets?.setAndrep?.reps = repsTextField?.text

                do{
                    try sets?.managedObjectContext?.save()
                    print("saved the sets and reps at row: ",indexpath.row)



                }catch{
                    print("Set and rep could not be added")
                }


                self.newMusclesTableView.reloadData()

            }
        }))

        inputAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
        self.present(inputAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)



    }



    let deleteButton = UITableViewRowAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { (rowAction, indexpath) in
        self.deleteMuscle(at: indexPath)
    }
    deleteButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

    return [editButton,deleteButton]
}
```

And in my CellForRowAt
I am trying to get the saved value and set it to the UILabel however it does not seem to be getting the value at all

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = newMusclesTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "muscleCell", for: indexPath) as? muscleListTableViewCell

    cell?.cellView.layer.cornerRadius = (cell?.cellView.frame.height)! / 2




    if let muscles = workout?.muscleList?[indexPath.row]{
        cell?.muscleTitle?.text = muscles.name
        cell?.myBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.btnAction(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        cell?.setsRepsLabel?.text = muscles.setAndrep?.sets ?? "did not get value"
    }


    return cell!
}
```

The UILabel is set to "did not get value" which means it could not get muscles.setAndrep?.sets

Can someone please help me on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I suspect the `setAndrep` relationship is nil.  In your edit action, you need to create a `SetRep` object, assign the correct values to its `sets` and `reps` properties, and then assign it to the `setAndrep` property of  `sets`.

Comment: I tried but the app crashes, perhaps I am doing it wrong
Could you please show me on how your method is? @pbasdf

Comment: @pbasdf In the console it shows 

results:  3  sets +  8  reps
saved the sets and reps at row:  1

which means it has executed the try sets?.managedObjectContext?.save() successfully however in the cell it doesn't show

Answer (score 1):

A few tips before I answer the question:

- try to minimise the spacing between lines so that you can see the whole method in a glance, this helps readability massively (you don't have to scroll or cast your eyes too far to see the whole method at once) (If you do later have a method that is too long to fit on a screen without any line spaces, that is usually an indicator it needs to be split into multiple methods)
- It might help you to extract the code within the save action out to its own method, so that you can re-use the code somewhere else that might want to save it, plus your code is more readable and modularised this way (google single responsibility principle, its a really useful way of programming that will save you so much time debugging things later =])

e.g.:

```
func saveSetAndRepToMuscleList(set: String, rep: String, setrep: SetRep) {
    ... // code that saves a set and rep to CoreData
}
```

that you would call this in the action callback:

```
let setrep = self.workout?.muscleList?[indexpath.row]
let sets = inputAlert.textFields?.first?.text
let reps = inputAlert.textFields?.last?.text
saveSetAndRepToMuscleList(sets, reps, setrep)
```

- To your question, do you have code that refreshes / fetches self.workout?.muscleList when changes are made?

This might be where you have an issue, since you have said the data is being saved to core data correctly but not shown in your UI. But alternatively it may be that it your variables are changing in your code but aren't actually being saved to core data. There exist some tools to read the contents of your core data db to enable you to check, like https://github.com/ChristianKienle/Core-Data-Editor

- You might want to check if using the context from a model object to perform a save is the issue

  `try sets?.managedObjectContext?.save()`

Personally I set up a single reference to the moc (Managed Object Context) and use the moc to call save etc. The way I usually obtain the moc is when the controller is created I get a reference from the app delegate, or a class I have made that manages the core data objects (a CoreDataManager of some sort).

- Check out this guide (and be aware that the talk is a few years out of date, but should still be good for getting the concepts right) https://academy.realm.io/posts/jesse-squires-core-data-swift/
- The code has been kept up to date https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQCoreDataKit